# Interfacing Burkert 4-20mA flow meter to controller

Tags: 4-20ma

I am figuring out how we can interface the flow meter to our controller before moving onto the software part. I have never worked with a 4-20mA interface hence just looking for some advice.

Below shows the connection diagram.
[image]

I am able to power the flow meter via the 12 V supply from our controller. The P- and P+ is the pulse output but that's not what we are looking to use.

The CH-1 is the input channel that needs the 4-20mA output from the sensor to be fed. Where can I find this output on the flow meter or how do I go about the connection from an electrical point of view, with reference to the above sketch?

[Here](https://www.burkert.co.nz/en/Media/plm/MAN/MA/MA8025-QS-UNIVERSAL-EU-EN.pdf) is the datasheet/manual for the sensor.

Any insights would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transmitter can be set to sink or source as per diagrams Fig 15 or 16.

[image]

So typically you'd want to use "sourcing" and connect the (-) input to power supply ground and the current source output of the transmitter to the (+) input.

That's probably correct but without a datasheet for the controller it's not possible to be completely sure.

Comment: I have made the above connections. How do I validate the connections and check the output?

Comment: Apply flow and check that the displays match?